# What happens when a WPF form is closed by selecting the "x" in the title bar?

Tags: c#, wpf

When the "x" is pressed in the title bar of a WPF form, where does the control go to? Is there a way of capturing this selection so that certain things can be done (like closing db connections) before exiting the code? Thanks for your help!  VR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to WinForms there are events on the form object that allow you to react to closes, including suppressing them. Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748948.aspx - documentation is in there.

Comment: Specificaly, this section: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748948.aspx#Closing_a_Window